# ASP.NET find textbox value in database retrieve offset value

Tags: asp.net, database, textbox

First of all today is my first day using ASP.NET and I have some limited knowledge in VBA. I have connected Access database to a project (web site) in ASP.Net, and I have only 1 textbox (TextBox1) and one Label (Label1).
I would like to find value from TextBox1 in Database (in second column "SIFRE") and retrieve value offset one column (third column "NAME") to Label1.

Or if some1 could suggest some online material so that I can learn how to use databases in ASP.NET.

I've searched the web but can not adjust results to my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft has an excellent series of tutorials on this. Just go to www.asp.net.

Comment: Maybe start here http://www.asp.net/, and look in the **learn** tab.  The question isn't that clear what you're looking to achieve.  Do you have any code to show?  Also, you mention `VBA` ?

Comment: @Christian I don't know how to be more clear. Based on a value in TextBox1 search second column of a database, if value found offset that value (position) 1 column and put that in the Label1. If not found exit sub. I don't know how to define columns in a database.
Anyway thanks for learning source, I'm gonna check that.

Comment: *How to be more clear:* `Web forms` or `MVC`?, `C#` or `VB.NET`?, where are you using `VBA`?  Your SQL would look something like `SELECT Name FROM TableName WHERE SIFRE = TextBox1.Text` maybe? Do you need to use **Access** or can you use **SQL server / Express**?  You mention learning databases, I'd suggest a more robust alternative to Access.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it should be written in VB 'cause I can probably adapt that based on my VBA knowledge. I've never used SQL, I've install it yesterday for the first time, because I read somewhere about Access database limitations. I am definitely gonna learn more in time but right now I have to solve this problem, to be able to read/write into database through web interface.

Comment: Line : SELECT Name FROM TableName WHERE SIFRE = TextBox1.Text doesn't work. How to declare column and table from SQL (I have it connected) in VB?